# How to combine two consumers?

Tags: scala

Given simple trait that consumes values of type T:

```
trait Consumer[-T] extends (T => Unit) {
  def +[U, P](other: Consumer[U]): Consumer[P] = ???
}
```

How to implement `+` function that combines two consumers into one that accepts valid supertype for AnyRef or wider type for AnyVal? For following cases:

-AnyRefs that have common supertype:

```
trait Base
trait A extends Base
trait B extends Base

val c1: Consumer[A] = _
val c2: Consumer[B] = _
val cc = c1 + c2 //cc must have type of Consumer[Base]
```

-AnyVals:

```
val c1: Consumer[Int] = _
val c2: Consumer[Long] = _
val cc = c1 + c2 //cc must have type of Consumer[Long]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to implement a concept of a *partial function*. When doing so, you need to be aware that you are sacrificing type safety for dynamicity. In a strongly-typed language you can't usually do that without some explicit hack, e.g. type cast or variance rules mitigation.

For example, standard Scala's `PartialFunction` does that for you: it allows to assign a function to another function disabling parameter contravariance check. As an example, having a type hierarchy

```
trait Animal
case class Dog() extends Animal
case class Cat() extends Animal
```

, it allows to "assign" a function of type `Dog => T` to a function of type `Animal => T` (what contradicts contravariance rules):

```
val pf: PartialFunction[Animal, Unit] = {
  case Dog() => println("dog")
}
```

At the expense of now possible match errors at runtime:

```
pf(Cat()) // MatchError
```

So, in general to combine multiple consumers in Scala you can do exactly same trick Scala language does for you when defining partial functions - change consumer parameter variance to covariant, i.e. `-T` to `+T`. To do this, use `@uncheckedVariance` annotation:

```
trait Consumer[+T, +V] extends (T@uncheckedVariance ⇒ V) {
  def handle(command: T@uncheckedVariance): V
}
```

Such variance allows to have a lookup table of consumers:

```
val lookup: Map[Class[_], Consumer[Animal]] = Map(
  classOf[Dog] → dogConsumer,
  classOf[Cat] → catConsumer
)
```

that can be used to implement dispatch based on (in this example case) class type.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible as you've envisioned it, because you need to guarantee the supertype consists of *only* the subtypes you've mentioned, or you will be unsound:

```
trait A
trait B extends A
trait C extends A
trait D extends A

val x: Consumer[A] = (new Consumer[B]) + (new Consumer[C])
x(new D)   // Uh-oh, nobody knows how to handle this!
```

With adequate forays into macros you probably could get this to work, but I would recommend that you first ask what exactly you want to accomplish, and see if there isn't a less fragile design that will also accomplish it.

For example, if you don't really care whether there is a certainty that something will be consumed, and you're just using the types to avoid obvious nonsense, you can do something like

```
abstract class Consumer[A: reflect.ClassTag] {
  def apply(a: A): Unit
  def consume(a: Any) {
    val c = implicitly[reflect.ClassTag[A]].runtimeClass
    if (c isInstance a) apply((c cast a).asInstanceOf[A])
  }
  def +[A1 >: A : reflect.ClassTag](that: Consumer[A1]) = {
    new Consumer[A1] {
      def apply(a1: A1) = { consume(a1); that.consume(a1) }
    }
  }
}
```